How to batch orders for different destinations in AnyLogic?
I'm building a model in AnyLogic where the Depot agent receives orders from the Customer agent. The depot needs to send these orders to one of the three transshipments.
Currently, I've managed to have my vehicle deliver orders, but each customer's order is delivered separately.
I tried to assign orders to the correct transshipment flow using SelectOutput but couldn't sort and batch them properly.
Question:
How can I ensure that orders are sorted to the correct transshipment so they can be batched and delivered together?
Here is my current processflow: Processflow which batches the order.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Hey, happy to help but strongly suggest you boil this down to a minimum-viable problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Aim to make our lives as easy as possible (to get quick and good answers). Some more tips if you prefer to write long "how do I?" questions: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community

All right, thanks for the tip. @Benjamin
